# Strange python highlighting using spf13-vim

Tags: vim

So I have been using spf13-vim recently, and I have tried changing the default colorscheme, but for some reason when I do I get strange highlighting of words. The highlighting seems to depend on the filetype such that my .txt and .py file will look different.

As an example, the following image shows the highlighting effect on `headnode`, `clusterRun`, `bwa`, and `vt`. This only occurs when I alter the colorscheme from default. So is there a way to stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like spell checking? `:verbose set spell? spelllang?`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker good catch, `:verbose set nospell` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

If you cannot find the highlighting this way, it may be *spell checking*; this goes on top of the syntax highlighting. You can list the corresponding highlight groups via

```
:hi SpellBad | hi SpellCap | hi SpellLocal | hi SpellRare
```

If you don't want spell checking,

```
:set nospell
```

turns it off.

#### Soap Box

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.